# Вычесть один список строк из другого. Python

Tags: python, list, diff

Даны два списка строк:

```
weekly_schedule = ['14:00 - 15:30\n4. ФИЗИЧЕСКАЯ КУЛЬТУРА', 'Пучкин А.В..', '15:40 - 17:10\n5. ПРАВОВОЕ ОБЕСПЕЧЕНИЕ ПРОФЕССИОНАЛЬНОЙ ДЕЯТЕЛЬНОСТИ\n', 'Кудряшова В.А.', '6. Н/Б']

name = ['Пучкин А.В..', 'Кудряшова В.А.']
```

Мне необходимо получить из них разницу (weekly_schedule - name), чтобы получилось:

```
['14:00 - 15:30\n4. ФИЗИЧЕСКАЯ КУЛЬТУРА', '15:40 - 17:10\n5. ПРАВОВОЕ ОБЕСПЕЧЕНИЕ ПРОФЕССИОНАЛЬНОЙ ДЕЯТЕЛЬНОСТИ\n', '6. Н/Б']
```

Перепробовал кучу методов, ничего не помогло.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно пересобрать список `weekly_schedule` с проверкой на вхождение элемента в список `name`

```
weekly_schedule = ['14:00 - 15:30\n4. ФИЗИЧЕСКАЯ КУЛЬТУРА', 'Пучкин А.В..', '15:40 - 17:10\n5. ПРАВОВОЕ ОБЕСПЕЧЕНИЕ ПРОФЕССИОНАЛЬНОЙ ДЕЯТЕЛЬНОСТИ\n', 'Кудряшова В.А.', '6. Н/Б']

name = ['Пучкин А.В..', 'Кудряшова В.А.']

res = [w for w in weekly_schedule if w not in name]

print(res)  # ['14:00 - 15:30\n4. ФИЗИЧЕСКАЯ КУЛЬТУРА', '15:40 - 17:10\n5. ПРАВОВОЕ ОБЕСПЕЧЕНИЕ ПРОФЕССИОНАЛЬНОЙ ДЕЯТЕЛЬНОСТИ\n', '6. Н/Б']
```

Comment: Спасибо, хороший метод